# Angular replace part of unsafe text with link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

My api returns an array of events (json) with the following property:

```
event.text
```

The text property contains a string based on user input, for example companyName, I want to list the text in a ng-repeat loop with a clickable link to the company. (the event.text could be "Dave added a new company Philips" where Philips and Dave are values from a database)

Because the companyname can have html tags that are unsafe e.g.

```
<a href="somenastyurl">dangerouscompany</a>
```

angular sanitizes the strings.

However some links should be shown in the front-end, to make sure only save links (created by my api) are shown. I decided to add two return values in the api:

```
event.links 
event.linknames
```

event.links contains links (urls to an item, the urls are always safe and not based on user input they use id's) and event.linknames the names that should be shown in the link. for example:

```
event.links = ["http://example.com/1","http://example.com/2"]
event.linknames = ["Dave","Philips"]
```

Ive edited event.text to contain tags like [0] to be replaced with links, a tag [0] should be replaced with a link to event.links[0] with the name of event.linksnames[0].
To replace the tags I made the following code (in my controller after the events are loaded).

```
angular.forEach($scope.events, function (value, key) {

    var arrayLength = value.links.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        value.Text = value.Text.replace("[" + i + "]", '<a ng-href"' + value.links[i] + '">' + value.linkNames[i]+'</a>');
    }
});
```

in my view :

```
 <div ng-repeat="e in events">
      <span >{{e.Text}} </span><br />
</div
```

The tag [0],[1] are replaced but the text is still sanitized and in the view the html tags are shown:

```
 <a ng-href"http://example.com/1">Dave</a> added a new company <a ng-href"http://example.com/2">Philips</a>
```

instead of the desired result:

```
 Dave added a new company Philips
```

where dave and philips are clickable links.

*Notes: I know the user could name his company my[0]company but the link would still be safe. Im using angular 1.6.4*

How can I make the replaced parts clickable and keep the non replaced part sanitized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own directive for simple unsafe html binding.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.events = [{
    Text: '<a href="http://example.com/1">Dave</a> added a new company <a href="http://example.com/2">Philips</a>'
  }];
})
app.directive("convertHtml", function() {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {
    scope.$watch(attr.convertHtml, function(value) {
      element.html(scope.$eval(attr.convertHtml));
    })
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="e in events">
    <span convert-html="e.Text"></span><br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But what if the company name contains HTML like the example in my question?

Comment: you mean this `<a href="somenastyurl">dangerouscompany</a>` instead of `Philips`?

Comment: I forgot a major benefit of the list with unsafe links, I can loop them and use WebUtility.HtmlEncode on them before returning them. now the html of the names is shown but the links are valid. If you can add that to the answer i will except it as it still uses your answer.

Comment: I'm not getting it. You can up-vote the answer if it helps you and modify it 
the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

use ng-sanitize - Linky Finds links in text input and turns them into html links. Supports http/https/ftp/mailto and plain email address links.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky

Comment: But what if the company name contains HTML like the example in my question?